# auth0 - redirect to /login after authentication

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I am stuck in strange error. I am trying to protect my client side route. I have this code

```
<Router history={history} component={App}>
          <div>


            <Route path="/login" render={(props) => <Login auth={auth} {...props} />} />
            <Route path="/apphome" render={(props) => <Apphome auth={auth} {...props} />} />
            <Route path="/apphome" render={(props) => (
                  !auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
                    <Redirect to="/login"/>
                  ) : (
                    <Apphome auth={auth} {...props} />
                  )
                )} />
            <Route path="/contacts" exact component ={Contacts} />
            <Route path="/mytodo" exact component ={Mytodo} />
            <Route path="/favorites" exact component ={Favorites} />
            <Route path="/mention" exact component ={Mention} />
            <Route path="/profile" exact component ={Profile} />
            <Route path="/buy" exact component ={Buy} />
            <Route path="/success" exact component ={Success} />
            <Route path="/cancel" exact component ={Cancel} />

          </div>
        </Router>
```

Now, i go to login page, login and it goes back to login page. But, when i dont protect this route and I have it unprotected like

It works perfectly and after login, i go to this Apphome component.

I am using react.js and auth0 . What's the issue here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 allows you to specify a callback route which will be called once you're authenticated. Login to auth0.com and list the callback routes you expect to be called. https://manage.auth0.com/#/applications

Then in your code you'll need to define the route:

```
<Route
    path="/callback"
    render={props => {
        handleAuthentication(props);
        return <Loading />;
    }}
/>
```

In the handleAuthentication function, redirect the user to any page after you validate their credentials:

```
handleAuthentication() {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
        if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
            this.setSession(authResult);
            this.history.replace("/");
        } else if (err) {
            this.history.replace("/auth/failed");
        }
    });
}
```

Now after auth0 has done the authentication, it should trigger your  callback. For example on dev: http://localhost:3000/callback. This should fire your your handleAuthentication function.